# Группировка блоков разный высоты в один контейнер

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как на bootstrap можно реализовать такой набор блоков? Запасной вариант для меня это js либа masonry. Каким решением вы б воспользовались?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну если блоки разной высоты, то возможно и лучше использовать js-библиотеку https://masonry.desandro.com/. Но можно скорее всего и без этого

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно так.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container mb-2">
  <div class="row pt-2">
    <div class="col">

      <!-- 1 card -->
      <div class="card mb-2">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x500/000/fff.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">

          <!-- 2 card -->
          <div class="card">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x800/000/fff.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col  pl-0">

          <!-- 3 card -->
          <div class="card">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x800/000/fff.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col pl-0">
      <div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col">

          <!-- 4 card -->
          <div class="card">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x800/000/fff.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col pl-0">

          <!-- 5 card -->
          <div class="card">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x800/000/fff.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- 6 card -->
      <div class="card">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x500/000/fff.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, как раз 4 версию и использую в проекте